# Error while upload App bundle in Play store: The Android App Bundle was not signed

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to upload an update to the last store. Google signing in enabled for the app.
I am getting the error "The Android App Bundle was not signed." even though I signed it from Android studio.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?